# Campos serem preenchidos automaticamente

Tags: jquery

Tenho um formulário onde o usuário conforme vai preenchendo os campos, as informações aparecem em uma div ao lado. Vejam:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse mesmo formulário tem uma busca automática de CEP, ou seja, quando digita o CEP, aparece automaticamente o endereço, bairro, etc.

O problema é que quando os campos são preenchidos automaticamente com o endereço, bairro, cidade e estado, não aparece na div ao lado. Como faço para fazer com que apareçam sem a necessidade de digitar? Vejam abaixo o código:

**CEP**

```
<script src="<?php echo $caminhoAbsoluto; ?>/assets/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" >
        $(document).ready(function() {
            function limpa_formulário_cep() {
                // Limpa valores do formulário de cep.
                $("#endereco").val("");
                $("#bairro").val("");
                $("#cidade").val("");
                $("#uf").val("");
                $("#ibge").val("");
            }
            //Quando o campo cep perde o foco.
            $("#cep").blur(function() {
                //Nova variável "cep" somente com dígitos.
                var cep = $(this).val().replace(/\D/g, '');
                //Verifica se campo cep possui valor informado.
                if (cep != "") {
                    //Expressão regular para validar o CEP.
                    var validacep = /^[0-9]{8}$/;
                    //Valida o formato do CEP.
                    if(validacep.test(cep)) {
                        //Preenche os campos com "..." enquanto consulta webservice.
                        $("#endereco").val("...");
                        $("#bairro").val("...");
                        $("#cidade").val("...");
                        $("#uf").val("...");
                        $("#ibge").val("...");
                        //Consulta o webservice viacep.com.br/
                        $.getJSON("//viacep.com.br/ws/"+ cep +"/json/?callback=?", function(dados) {
                            if (!("erro" in dados)) {
                                //Atualiza os campos com os valores da consulta.
                                $("#endereco").val(dados.logradouro);
                                $("#bairro").val(dados.bairro);
                                $("#cidade").val(dados.localidade);
                                $("#uf").val(dados.uf);
                                $("#ibge").val(dados.ibge);
                            } //end if.
                            else {
                                //CEP pesquisado não foi encontrado.
                                limpa_formulário_cep();
                                alert("CEP não encontrado.");
                            }
                        });
                    } //end if.
                    else {
                        //cep é inválido.
                        limpa_formulário_cep();
                        alert("Formato de CEP inválido.");
                    }
                } //end if.
                else {
                    //cep sem valor, limpa formulário.
                    limpa_formulário_cep();
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

**FORMULÁRIO**

```
<form method="post">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Loja</label>
            <input type="text" name="Loja" id="loja" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>CNPJ</label>
            <input type="text" name="CNPJ" id="cnpj" class="form-control" data-mask="00.000.000/0000-00" data-mask-selectonfocus="true">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Nome do Responsável</label>
            <input type="text" name="NomeResponsavel" id="responsavel" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Email</label>
            <input type="email" name="Email" id="email" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Telefone</label>
            <input type="text" name="Telefone" id="telefone" class="form-control" data-mask="(00) 0000-0000" data-mask-selectonfocus="true">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Celular</label>
            <input type="text" name="Celular" id="celular" class="form-control" data-mask="(00) 00000-0000" data-mask-selectonfocus="true">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>CEP</label>
            <input type="text" name="CEP" id="cep" class="form-control" data-mask="00000-000" data-mask-selectonfocus="true">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Endereço Completo</label>
            <input type="text" name="Endereco" id="endereco" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Bairro</label>
            <input type="text" name="Bairro" id="bairro" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Cidade</label>
            <input type="text" name="Cidade" id="cidade" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Estado</label>
            <input type="text" name="Estado" id="estado" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>                                                
</div>
</form>
```

**DIV ONDE APARECE AS INFORMAÇÕES DIGITADAS**

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="card card-profile">
        <div class="card-avatar" style="background-color: #fff; padding: 10px">
            <i class="far fa-address-card fa-5x"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <h6 class="category text-gray"><p id="paragrafoLoja"></p></h6>
            <h4 class="card-title"><p id="paragrafoCNPJ"></p></h4>
            <p class="card-content">
                <p id="paragraforesponsavel"></p>
                <p id="paragrafoemail"></p>
                <p id="paragrafotelefone"></p>
                <p id="paragrafocelular"></p>
                <p id="paragrafoendereco"></p>
                <p id="paragrafobairro"></p>
                <p id="paragrafocidade"></p>
                <p id="paragrafoestado"></p>
        </p>            
    </div>
</div>
```

JQUERY

```
    <script>
        var loja = document.querySelector('#loja');
        var paragrafoLoja = document.querySelector('#paragrafoLoja');
        loja.addEventListener('keyup', function () {
        paragrafoLoja.innerHTML = loja.value;
        });
        var cnpj = document.querySelector('#cnpj');
        var paragrafoCNPJ = document.querySelector('#paragrafoCNPJ');
        cnpj.addEventListener('keyup', function () {
        paragrafoCNPJ.innerHTML = cnpj.value;
        });
        var responsavel = document.querySelector('#responsavel');
        var paragrafoResponsavel = document.querySelector('#paragraforesponsavel');
        responsavel.addEventListener('keyup', function () {
        paragrafoResponsavel.innerHTML = "<div align='left' style='padding: 10px'><strong>Responsável:</strong> <br>" + responsavel.value + "</div>";
        });
        var email = document.querySelector('#email');
        var paragrafoEmail = document.querySelector('#paragrafoemail');
        email.addEventListener('keyup', function () {
        paragrafoEmail.innerHTML = "<div align='left' style='padding: 10px'><strong>Email:</strong> <br>" + email.value + "</div>";
        });
        var telefone = document.querySelector('#telefone');
        var paragrafoTelefone = document.querySelector('#paragrafotelefone');
        telefone.addEventListener('keyup', function () {
        paragrafoTelefone.innerHTML = "<div align='left' style='padding: 10px'><strong>Telefone:</strong> " + telefone.value + "</div>";
        });
        var celular = document.querySelector('#celular');
        var paragrafoCelular = document.querySelector('#paragrafocelular');
        celular.addEventListener('keyup', function () {
        paragrafoCelular.innerHTML = "<div align='left' style='padding: 10px'><strong>Celular:</strong> " + celular.value + "</div>";
        });
        var endereco = document.querySelector('#endereco');
        var paragrafoEndereco = document.querySelector('#paragrafoendereco');
        endereco.addEventListener('keyup', function () {
        paragrafoEndereco.innerHTML = "<div align='left' style='padding: 10px'><strong>Endereço:</strong> <br>" + endereco.value + "</div>";
        });
        var bairro = document.querySelector('#bairro');
        var paragrafobairro = document.querySelector('#paragrafobairro');
        bairro.addEventListener('keyup', function () {
        paragrafobairro.innerHTML = "<div align='left' style='padding: 10px'><strong>Bairro:</strong> <br>" + bairro.value + "</div>";
        });
        var cidade = document.querySelector('#cidade');
        var paragrafoCidade = document.querySelector('#paragrafocidade');
        cidade.addEventListener('keyup', function () {
        paragrafoCidade.innerHTML = "<div align='left' style='padding: 10px'><strong>Cidade:</strong> " + cidade.value + "</div>";
        });
        var estado = document.querySelector('#estado');
        var paragrafoEstado = document.querySelector('#paragrafoestado');
        estado.addEventListener('keyup', function () {
        paragrafoEstado.innerHTML = "<div align='left' style='padding: 10px'><strong>Estado:</strong> " + estado.value + "</div>";
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Em vez de usar métodos JavaScript, use o `.on()` do jQuery nos eventos. Por exemplo, em vez de usar:

```
var bairro = document.querySelector('#bairro');
var paragrafobairro = document.querySelector('#paragrafobairro');
bairro.addEventListener('keyup', function () {
   paragrafobairro.innerHTML = "<div align='left' style='padding: 10px'><strong>Bairro:</strong> <br>" + bairro.value + "</div>";
});
```

Use:

```
var bairro = $('#bairro');
var paragrafobairro = $('#paragrafobairro');
bairro.on('keyup', function () {
   paragrafobairro.html("<div align='left' style='padding: 10px'><strong>Bairro:</strong> <br>" + bairro.val() + "</div>");
});
```

Nem precisa criar variáveis, pode usar assim:

```
$('#bairro').on('keyup', function () {
   $('#paragrafobairro').html("<div align='left' style='padding: 10px'><strong>Bairro:</strong> <br>" + this.value + "</div>");
});
```

E após o AJAX do CEP se processado, dispare o evento `keyup` com `.trigger("keyup")` em todos os campos que vão para a div:

```
$("#endereco, #bairro, #cidade, #uf").trigger("keyup");
```

Ficando assim:

```
if (!("erro" in dados)) {
  //Atualiza os campos com os valores da consulta.
  $("#endereco").val(dados.logradouro);
  $("#bairro").val(dados.bairro);
  $("#cidade").val(dados.localidade);
  $("#uf").val(dados.uf);
  $("#ibge").val(dados.ibge);
  $("#endereco, #bairro, #cidade, #uf").trigger("keyup");
} //end if.
else {
  //CEP pesquisado não foi encontrado.
  limpa_formulário_cep();
  alert("CEP não encontrado.");
}
```